# Как закачать файл на сервер при помощи Spring 3?

Tags: spring, java

Здравствуйте.
Какой в `Spring 3` механизм загрузки файлов на сервер?
Мне нужен *пример*. Только без специальных тегов спригна а, например, со стандартными HTML-тегами и HTML-формой.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В `Spring 3` это довольно просто.
Для начала надо включить дополнительные две библиотеки:

```
commons-fileupload.jar
commons-io.jar
```

Затем в конфигурационном файле `app-servlet.xml` объявить дополнительный бин:

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" 
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"/>
```

Допустим, мы отправляем на сервер два параметра: *текстовое поле* и непосредственно сам *файл*. Тогда в *классе-контроллере* объявляем какой-нибудь метод, который будет принимать эти два параметра:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/renderFile.htm")
public void saveFile(@RequestParam("MyFileName") MultipartFile file,
                     @RequestParam("fileName") String fileName) {
    System.out.println("Вот размер файла:");
    System.out.println(file.getSize());
    //Ну и все, что надо произвести с этими входными параметрами    
}
```

Не забываем указать *тип посылаемых данных* (`enctype="multipart/form-data"`) ну и *кодировку* (в некоторых случаях она необходима).
Ну вот и все.